# Ag-grid server side pagination with client side sort & filter

Tags: reactjs, pagination, ag-grid, server-side, ag-grid-react

I am using React Ag-grid version `25.3.0`. I'm implementing server side pagination and I have added the following properties to the Grid

```
rowModelType='serverSide'
paginationPageSize={PAGE_SIZE}
cacheBlockSize={PAGE_SIZE}
serverSideStoreType={ServerSideStoreType.Partial}
```

Then, inside the `onGridReady` function, I have configured the datasource

```
  const onGridReady = useCallback((params) => {
    params.api.showLoadingOverlay();
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource({
      getRows: (params) => {
        getData()
          .then((data) => {
            params.success({ rowData: data.rowData, rowCount: data.rowCount });
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            params.fail();
          });
      },
    });
  }, []);
```

With this, the server-side pagination is working fine. However, ag-grid is expecting the column filtering and sorting to happen in the server as well. Meaning, every time I click on a column header to sort it, the `getRows` function is fired. But, I would like to sort and filter records in the grid client-side. I want the sort and filtering work just like how it would work for `rowModelType='clientSide'`. I know it will only filter/sort the current page that I am on, but that's fine.

Help please !!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If pagination is server-side, that means that you have only part of the data at the time in the frontend. So you would only be to sort the part of the data you have (one page) which is pointless.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Yeah, true. It's not very functional.. but I would like to see if that's possible with Ag-grid.